# How can I use Gorouter and Pgeview together to achieve the navigation in the Flutter web app with PageView builder and named routes?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-pageview, flutter-go-router

I want to achieve Url Navigation in Flutter Web using Gorouter and PageView-builder built within a single scaffold. I want to change the PageView item only and retain the remaining parts of the scaffold without rendering them again.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dynamic page. And when navigating pass the id in the slug. Using the slug fetch data. To make this in a single scaffold use the slug inside the scaffold to create some widgets that will dynamically build using the slug.

```dart
GoRoute(
  name: yourPage,
  path: '/yourPage/:slug';,
  builder: (context, state) {
    final id = state.params['slug'];
    return YourPage(
      key: state.pageKey,
      slug: id,
    );
  },
),
```

Comment: Can you please provide me the guidance on how can I implement the other side I mean the Widget side where I am using the PageView.builder?

Let's say the page names are:

Page1,
Page2,
Page3,
Page4,

Comment: Are your pages static?

Comment: Yes they are static Pages, within PageView. I am using PageView.builder for scalability.

Comment: But how do you update the url/path when swiping between pages?